# Writing an object to the location.hash using Vue.js and URI.js

Tags: vue.js, uri

I have a list of items along with a filter. I'd like to store the filter options in the `window.location.hash` property, so that I have nice sharable urls.

I am struggling to build a hash fragment which will work, using URI.js.

- Vue.js `2.4.4`
- URI.js `1.19.0`

## What I've done so far

```js
import Uri from "urijs";
let UriFragment = require('../../node_modules/urijs/src/URI.fragmentURI.js');

// UpdateHash method
let uri = new Uri(window.location.href);
uri.fragment({
    providers: ['best', 'bestest'],
    sort: 'recommended'
});

window.location.hash = uri.fragment();
```

## What's happening?

`example.com/list-of-things#![object Object]`

## What I expected to happen

As per the docs about 'fiddling with the fragment' http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/

`example.com/list-of-things#providers=best&providers=bestest&sort=recommended`

## Question

How can I ensure that the plugin for URI.js is loaded and working? Then move onto figuring out why it's not outputting a formatted uri fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew as soon as I posted, I would find the answer.

I was trying to use code for `URI.fragmentURI.js` when in fact I wanted `URI.fragmentQuery.js`.

Swapping to the correct plugin for the library has solved this problem.